# There is only one monoidal monotone $(\mathbb N, \le, 0, +) \to (\mathbb N, \leq, 1, *)?$

Tags: category-theory

This is a question in [Seven Sketches in Compositionality](https://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf), exercise 2.45 question 2.

Answer given on page 272 said that only one monoidal monotone is: $f(n) = 1.$

But I think $f(n) = 2^n$ should also be correct answer.

Please someone point out my misunderstanding or error here?

Comment: I think you are right, it might be an error in the book.

Comment: If I am correct, a monoidal monotone map between given poset categories subject to only three conditions:
 (i) $a\le b\implies f(a)\le f(b),$ (ii) $1\le f(0),$ and (iii) $f(a)f(b)\le f(a+b).$ So, I do not see any wrong with your argument.

Comment: I'm certain this is a mistake in the book - our group has discussed the same thing. Actually $m^n$ works, for any $m$.

Comment: @Nathaniel I think you mean for any $ m \in \mathbb N$

Comment: @SharkXu yes, of course